# adding a second back button to a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I already have the automatically generated back button in the top left corner, but I'd like to add a UIButton that does the same at the bottom of my view.

Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF you are using a UINavigation controller, you can register a button handler and add the code

```
[[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This will provide the same functionality as the back button generated when you add a view to the view stack.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just hook the button up to a method that calls `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]` (or `NO`, depending on your wishes).